# mySQL Update student attendance

Tags: mysql

Hello guys currently I am working on the database related to the student attendance tracking. The three main tables that I am dealing with is `Students`, `Modules` and `Attendance`. The structure looks like the following:

- Students (studentID, name , surname , email , attendance),
- Modules (moduleID, module, startTime, EndTime),
- Attendance (studentID , scanTime).

And basically what I need to do here is to increase attendance in (students) table by +1 if the scanTime in (attendance) is between the startTime and EndTime in (module).Im not sure do I need to use any joins here or is it going to be just IF statements.

I have been trying to update attendance by doing this

```
SELECT s.Student_ID,s.Attendance,a.ScanTime,a.ClassRoom,m.Module,m.Room, m.StartTime,m.EndTime 
FROM students AS s,attendance a,modules m 
IF a.ScanTime < m.StartTime AND a.ScanTime > m.EndTime
UPDATE students 
SET s.attendance = attendance + 1
WHERE s.Student_ID = "X111111111";
```

However it did not work. Can anyone tell me how I can update attendance using something else.

Comment: Read the MySQL documentation for UPDATE query syntax.

Comment: This may be beyond the scope of the question, but where do you store which modules should a student attend? As far as the question goes, you should be saving your last time when you looked up and then each time look further, so that the counter doesn't need to get rebuilt, but is in fact like you want it - incremented.

Comment: I don't store that information about the module .. as in my understanding I don't really need that.

Answer (score 0):

using join statement at

```
FROM students AS s,attendance a,modules m
```

example

```
FROM students s join attendance a on s.[column] = a.[column]
join modules m on a.[column] = m.[column]
```

and add s. to avoid ambiguous at

```
SET s.attendance = s.attendance + 1
```

check your IF statement
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html.